Analog auto balance bridge method for finding impedance of unknown

Hi all, I'm trying to find impedance of unknown (DUT - Inductor) with analog auto balance bridge method. I'm bit confuse about its working procedure, so need to know more about its working procedure.  Here, VG1 is sine wave with voltage of 3V, 100kHz. And all the voltmeters are showing 112.36mV to 112. 38mV.Kindly please help me to clear this. Thanks in advance.

The op-amps probably need positive and negative supplies. They can't output zero or negative potentials without. Start with that.
